# Matrix and OFFSET/MATCH/INDEX

Tags: microsoft-excel

So I have a sort of matrix in excel with IDs on the y axis and names on the x-axis. The matrix contains 0 if the name does not relate to the ID and 1 if it does. Now I want to create a function where I can get the ID associated with each name based on  whether the matrix shows a 1 or a 0.

I was trying to use an offset function with match and index functions but I can't get it to work. Any ideas?

[Simplified version of what I am working with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqUrP.png)

Thanks a lot,

Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the accompanying image which has row and column identifiers, use this in J2 and fill down.

```
=INDEX(B:B, MATCH(1, INDEX(C:F, 0, MATCH(I2, C$1:F$1, 0))))
```

[image]